# Is it possible to use switch case for more than one array.indexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance

I have some set of if conditions for a particular array using javascript

```
if (activity.indexOf("strategy session") != -1) {
    $("#FoPStrategySession").show();
}

if (activity.indexOf("sessions") != -1) {
    $("#acprojectname").show();
    if (supportmodel == "Level") {
        $(".accombohide").hide();
        $("[title='Test']").val("NA");
        $("[title='Test2']").val("NA");
    }
}

if (activity.indexOf("virtual") != -1) {
    if (supportmodel == "Level") {
        $(".lvl3_consult").hide();
        $("[title='Test']").val("NA");
        $("[title='Test2']").val("NA");
    }
}

if (activity.indexOf("Other") != -1) {
    $("#acactivityother").show();
}
```

Is there any other way to **efficiently** write this code using switch case or any other method?

Comment: Do you expect multiple of these keywords to show up in the array? How large is the array?

Comment: for my taste I see no problem with your code. there is not much repetition and it's easily readable

Comment: try posting this at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). this is the appropriate place for questions about efficiency improvements.

Comment: @Bergi : The array has around 10-12 items.

Comment: @Eliran Malka : I will try posting there also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No need for multiple `if()`  or `switch()` statements.

You can reduce cyclomatic complexity (now is 7) and end up with a better code. Note that have been refactored some jQuery selectors `$('[title="Test"], [title="Test2"]').val('NA');` and using comparison operators `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=` respectively.

> "The cyclomatic complexity of a section of source code is the count of the number of linearly independent paths through the source code." -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Also have been created variables to avoid jQuery searching the DOM multiple times for the same selectors.

Code:

```
var $foPStrategySession = $('#FoPStrategySession'),
    $acprojectname =  $('#acprojectname'),
    $titleTests = $('[title="Test"], [title="Test2"]'),
    $acactivityother = $('#acactivityother'),
    $accombohide = $('.accombohide'),
    $lvl3_consult = $('.lvl3_consult'),
    obj = {
        'strategy session': function () {
            $foPStrategySession.show();
        },
        'sessions': function () {
            $acprojectname.show();
            if (supportmodel === 'Level') {
                $accombohide.hide();
                $titleTests.val('NA');
            }
        },
        'virtual': function () {
            if (supportmodel === 'Level') {
                $lvl3_consult.hide();
                $titleTests.val('NA');
            }
        },
        'Other': function () {
            $acactivityother.show();
        }
    };

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (o) {
        if (activity.indexOf(o) !== -1) {
            obj[o]();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This neither is more readable, more efficient or even does the same as the code in the OP.

Comment: @Bergi can you check again please

Comment: changing equality operators *may* result in more efficiency, but it changes the intent. `===` and `==` have very different implications on the program flow (cohersion or not..), and cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: Does that mean the above mentioned code is similar to the one I written?

Comment: Yes it is the same code but no need to write `if` or `switch` statements

Comment: @Yosvel Quintero : I will try this code and also the one mentioned by Matias.

Comment: @Yosvel Quintero : thanks for the code,now I find easy to maintain also.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't be querying the DOM all over again:

```
var strategySession = $("#FoPStrategySession");
var acprojectname = $('#acprojectname');

// and so on..
```

Later you'll access these DOM elements with their references created above.

Now you can use `Array.prototype.forEach` to simplify your code with a `switch`:

```
activity.forEach(function(act) {
    // I suggest you that you lower case each activity
    // to avoid further issues...
    switch(act.toLowerCase())
         case "strategy session":
              strategySession.show();
              break;

         // other cases...

         default:
             throw Error("Not supported activity");
    }
});
```

**Side note: I understand that `activity` is an *array*. Otherwise you would be checking if `activity` is some particular `string` using equality operators and my answer should need some refactor. Comment out my answer if I was mistaken about `activity` being an `array`...**.

Comment: So by doing this method, will it be more efficent and also the number lines will be decreased right?

Comment: Using a `switch` inside a loop will do something different than the original code if an item appears multiple times in the array.

Comment: @Bergi Well, it will fall in the same case many times... I don't know if this is a problem for the OP